# Exporting a key words in google sheets

Tags: function, text, google-sheets, keyword

I have keywords in one *column (A1:A5)* separated by comma:

- keyword1, keyword2, keyword3
- keyword2, keyword4
- keyword1
- keyword1
- keyword2

And I would like to export all 4 keywords in one row: (keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4)

I have used `=(arrayformula(SPLIT(A1:A5,",",TRUE)))` and I have received a 2D table. I am looking for option to show all the keywords in one row. I will use the function UNIQUE at the end.

Thank you.

Comment: And how can I remove duplicates?
I have list of words in `C7 = keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4,keyword4` - focus on two keywords4, one without space at the beginning
then I use `=SUBSTITUTE(C7,", ",",")` to remove spaces and the `UNIQUE` for removing duplicates. Unfortunately the `UNIQUE` does not work. There is still 2x keyword4

Comment: (see `https://docs.google.com/a/btlnet.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZTq6Xg1bm8w_dFBtnGKDR3Kvq86gmUw3W7SkpPYqw4g/edit?usp=sharing`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try (did not check):

`=join(", ",unique(transpose(split(join(", ", A1:A5), ", "))))`

Comment: Great, the command 'join' is what I need. Thank you.
I have used this:
`=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(UNIQUE(JOIN(",",C13:C21)),",")))`
and that works perfectly